# Apache Server - ErrorLog - What does the 'static' wsgi:error mean?

Tags: html, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, error-logging

I am running a Flask application on Apache Server - Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) and I am getting lots of 'static' wsgi:error entries in Apache ErrorLog (LogLevel is set to error) :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrQmZ.png)

[Wed Jan 17 17:43:08.342412 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 1920667:tid 140691102705408] [remote 10.3.2.230:12626] static
[Wed Jan 17 17:43:08.563909 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 1920667:tid 140690956732160] [remote 10.3.2.230:12626] static
[Wed Jan 17 17:43:08.767332 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 1920667:tid 140691102705408] [remote 10.3.2.233:28285] static
[Wed Jan 17 17:43:08.784697 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 1920667:tid 140690956732160] [remote 10.3.2.233:61770] static
[Wed Jan 17 17:43:08.787472 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 1920667:tid 140691102705408] [remote 10.3.2.230:12626] static

...

It looks like the entry is added for each .css or .js file that is loaded in the application html page.
Could someone please advise what do those entries mean and how to get rid of them ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.